# Use the weak law of large numbers to show running average of a coin converges

Tags: probability

> Toss an unbiased coin 1000 times.  The running average $ \bar{Y}_n $ converges to $0.5$.  The weak law of large numbers says:
>   $$ \displaystyle P(0.4 < \bar{Y}_n < .6) \leq \frac{1}{40}$$

Let $Y1, Y2, . . .$ be any collection of IID r.v.’s (independent and identically distributed random variables) with common mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  Then for every $\varepsilon>0$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( \bigg| \frac{1}{n} (Y_1 + \dots + Y_n) - \mu \bigg| > \varepsilon \right) = 0 $$

Applying Chebychev's Inequality shows that for $\bar{Y}_n = \frac{1}{n}(Y_1+\dots+Y_n)$

$$ P(|\bar{Y}_n -\mu|\geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n \varepsilon^2} \to 0 $$

Here's my work so far:

Coin tosses have Bernoulli Random distribution so $E[\bar{Y}_n] = \frac{np}{n} = 0.5$ and $VAR[\bar{Y}_n] = \frac{np(1-p)}{n} = \frac{1}{4}$

$$ P(0.4 < \bar{Y}_n < .6) $$

$$ = P(-0.1 < \bar{Y}_n - 0.5 < 0.1) $$

$$ \Rightarrow P(| \bar{Y}_n - 0.5 | < 0.1) $$

But to use the WLLN don't we need greater than or equal?  So we do:

$$ = 1 - P(| \bar{Y}_n - 0.5 | \geq 0.1) $$

By Chebychev's inequality this is

$$ \leq 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{n \varepsilon}  $$

$$ = 1 - \frac{1/4}{1000*(0.1)^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{40} = \frac{39}{40} $$

I think my confusion is at the step of applying the WLLN's $\varepsilon$ inequality

Comment: Isn´t the inequality of the exercise $P(|\overline Y_n-0.5 |\geq 0.1)=P(0.6\leq \overline Y_n \leq 0.4)\leq \frac{1}{40} ?$ In this case your calculation is right.

Comment: Oh maybe it should be, thank you(: